# Tkinter- Exit without saving- Warning dialogue box or askquestion

Tags: python, tkinter

### Exit without Saving

How should I program my ***exit*** function that if user exit without saving then it should pop a question

```
def main(self):
    ...
    file.add_command(label="New",command=lambda: self.new())
    file.add_command(label="Open",command=lambda: self.load())
    file.add_command(label="Save",command=lambda: self.save())
    file.add_command(label="Exit",command=self.exit)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file)

def exit(self):
        result = askquestion("Exit", "Are You Sure Without Saving?", icon='warning')
        if result == "yes":
            exit()
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a **global** variable called

```
hasBeenSaved = False
```

When you call the save() function, switch that global boolean `hasBeenSaved` to `True`.

If the user does **anything** else to change their file, set `hasBeenSaved` back to `False` .

Now, when you are going through your exit() function, if `hasBeenSaved` is `False`, prompt the user for:

> "Are you sure you wanna exit without saving?"

Hope this helps!